# Spark Streaming Scala: save to text file only when sliding window is finished

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm developing a spark streaming app in scala and now that i'm finished my first version I want to improve performance.

My spark app currently is printing some important alerts of mine on every batch which means i've got new text files being generated in the range of seconds whereas i'd prefer if the computations are performed but writing to file occurs only when my sliding window expires which is in the range of 10mins.

An example of the rdd of interest follows:

```
val s = events.flatMap(_.split("\n")) //split block into lines of single json events
              .map(toMyObject) //convert raw json to MyObject
              .filter(checkCondition) //filter events based on condition
              .map(x => (x._1,1L)) //count alerts based on area
              .reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, _ - _, Minutes(window_length), Seconds(sliding_interval), 2) //count alerts per area
              .repartition(1)
              .saveAsTextFiles("alerts")
```

Comment: do I understand correctly that you want to have non-overlapping windows? in this case your slide duration should be also 10 minutes - then it will output each file every 10 minutes, including calculations on previous 10 minutes of data. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @AlexLarikov yes exactly just tried it and it works... it also lowers cpu utilization so thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments: to implement non-overlapping window slide duration should be the same as window duration.

I.e. in example above with window duration 10 minutes, if slide duration is set to 10 minutes as well - it will produce file once per 10 minutes including calculations on all data within those 10 minutes.